# Node Question: How to Convert Length to Integer

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

Just ran into this strange issue where I am trying to have one Input Node give a value of "10" to two different inputs, where one is 10" and the other is simply a float 10:

[image]

But it doesn't work.  I've noticed that when I hover over the Length Input (value of 10") I get this little popup that says: ".254 float."

[image]

It would be really helpful to understand what is happening here, so I can create an input that adding a value of "10" will simultaneously put 10 in both the Length (10") and the Multiply inputs.

Comment: Looks like two units are mixed here. 10" == 0.254m

Comment: Add a value node set to 10 and a math node to convert to meters from inches ( * 0,0254) before plugging into the nodes. Internally all computations are done in SI (or Blender Units, rather, the point is they adhere to the SI)

Comment: Thanks so much.  I always work in imperial units and I forgot the default was metric and this (duh!) was the cause of my frustration.  I really appreciate you guys weighing in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have changed the unit system from *Metric* to *Imperial*.

This way, all input fields that require length measurements are automatically converted to the unit you selected.

Unfortunately, in *Geometry Nodes* in the spreadsheet, all values are still evaluated and displayed metrically. All input fields that do not explicitly use a length are also calculated metrically.

You would therefore always have to multiply your float values by $0.0254$:

[image]

However, in *Geometry Nodes* you have the possibility to connect a free socket of your group input with the input *Length*. This will create a new input, which will automatically be interpreted as a length and thus adopt the selected unit.

So you have the possibility to set an input field of the group input to your chosen length unit.

[image]

Comment: Thank yo for this solution @quellenform, which is as simple as I was hoping it would be ;)